# Interact with Ruby Padrino console through Entrypoint command in docker-compose

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to start up a Padrino console (similar to Rails console).

Here's my ENTRYPOINT command in `Dockerfile`

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

I want to start the console when the env variable value is `$CONSOLE = Y`

Here's the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script

```
if [ "$CONSOLE" = "Y" ];
then
    echo "Starting Padrino console"
    bundle exec padrino console
else
#something else
fi
```

However, when I run `docker-compose up` with environment variable `CONSOLE = Y`, the console begins to start but ends with `Switch to Inspect mode`. I tried a lot of solutions online, and while `docker-compose exec <container-name> bundle exec padrino console` might work, it exceeds the memory and kills both the console process and the server running on the container.

How can I just start the console in the `docker-compose up` command?

EDIT
Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
    - "36081:36081"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    <other-services>
    container_name: application
    environment:
    - MIGRATE=$MIGRATE
    - CONSOLE=$CONSOLE
  <other-services>
```

Comment: can you show docker-compose file?

Comment: @Adiii I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So according to this [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3081), you can not allocate tty in docker-compose because it starts multiple containers.

> That is expected behaviour. up is not interactive. It can start
>   multiple containers, so you can't have a single terminal that has
>   stdin open for multiple containers.

as there is single service in your docker-compose so you can try with `run` command instead of `up`

```
docker-compose run app
```

or the other option is to start all the container then run with `docker attach`
but first, you need

```
docker-compose -d
```

then

```
docker attach container_name
```

you might need `tty` flag to true as well

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    tty: true
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was using the attach approach, but didn't set the `tty` flag. It works!